# Is it possible to create more rows than original data using GROUPBY and COUNT(*)?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT "domain", site_domain, pageurl, count (*) FROM impressions WHERE imp_date > '20150718' AND insertion_order_id = '227363'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

It was an incorrectly conceived query this I understand, but it took over 30 minutes to run, while just pulling the data without a `count` and `groupby` took just 20 seconds.

My question being is it possible that there are more rows created than the original data set?

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ? This SQL shouldn't work on many...

Comment: No - what you're likely experiencing is that with the `GROUP BY` it is comparing the values of all of the `site_domain` and `pageurl` columns to get the distinct values.  My guess is that those are not indexed and you're making sql cry trying to do those comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The only time that an aggregation query will return *more* rows than in the original data set is when two conditions are true:

- There are no matching rows in the query.
- There is no `group by`.

In this case, the aggregation query returns one row; without the aggregation you would have no rows.

Otherwise, `GROUP BY` *combines* rows together, so the result cannot be larger than the original data.

When you are comparing time spent for returning a result set, you need to distinguish between time to first row and time to last row.  When you execute a simple `SELECT`, you are inclined to measure the time to the first row returned.  However, a `group by` needs to process *all* the data before returning any rows (under most circumstances).  Hence, it would be better to compare the time to the *last* row returned by the simple query.

Comment: I was comparing time to last row in both scenarios, I understand the GROUP BY would add time but this seemed to be a huge addition.